# How to add a JavaScript function with comma separated id's into the ontouchend attribute of an element via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this JavaScript function with four comma separated id's in it.

```
function expCountDown(id1, id2, id3, id4)
```

And at the moment I'm trying to append an ontouchend attribute containing the JavaScript function to an element through jQuery....... and it's not working.

```
$("#gaskup1_cash").bind("touchstart", function(){
$(".dialogOKtext").attr("ontouchend": "expCountDown('gaskup1_check', 'gaskup1_count', 'gaskup1_expired', 'gaskup1')");
});
```

I've successfully tried doing this with JavaScript functions with just one or no id's, so I suppose it's due to the commas in the function.

I know this is a horrendous way to go about this. But just for the sake of argument, is this even possible? And in any wich case, how/why?

Comment: How did you come to the realization that doing that is going to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if binding the `touchend` event is *exactly* what you want. If that's the case you should do it as follows.

```
$(".dialogOKtext").on("touchend", function(){
  expCountDown('gaskup1_check', 'gaskup1_count', 'gaskup1_expired', 'gaskup1');
});
```

As a remark, as of jQuery 1.7 the preferred method to bind event handlers is [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info on binding :)
However, it's not the binding of the ontouchend event I'm having trouble with, but rather adding an ontouchend attribute to the elements with the class dialogOKtext.